# How to get the test outcome programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I am using the Visual Studio agents to run VS coded UI tests on a remote test server (the test agent) from my own developer machine (the test controller).

When running tests locally, I was able to access and read the TRX results file that is created once the test had completed, but I am unable to access this file on the remote test server since the TRX results file remains within the Visual Studio folder on the test controller.

The reason I want to access the results file programmatically as I have code to read the file and then to send out the result as an automated email.

So, is there any way to get the outcome of the test programmatically so that I can send out the results email automatically?

Ideally, I would be able to get access to the TRX results file from the test server but I'm not sure if this is feasible or possible.

Comment: Do you want to get the test outcome of each test (unit test...) by the test itself or the test outcome of the whole test run?

Comment: Both preferably, but it would be my priority to get the outcome of the whole test run.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the coded ui inside of a load test, you can set it to write to the LoadTest2010 database. From there you can set up ways to get the results and trigger events as with any database.